# Production Error:Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing on codeigniter from last two months. But when I pushed my code to Web hosting site today, I am getting this error. Few things I have checked 100 times:

- Controller method says `$this->load->model('myModel');`
- In the model folder I have `myModel.php`
- It starts with

> ```
> <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');<br/>
>
> class MyModel extends CI_Model {
>   public function __construct()
>   {
>    parent::__construct();
>   }
> ```

I have checked spelling mistakes or some typo but everything seems to be fine.

Comment: put all to lowercase .. sometime upload tent to rename files depending of what client your using... your code seems to be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A name of model should be lower case: `mymodel_model.php` on `/application/models/` directory.

The mymodel_model.php contains:

```
class Mymodel_model extends CI_Model {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

And call it as:

```
$this->load->model('mymodel');
```

A `_model` string MUST be on:

- filename of model `mymodel_model.php`
- a class name with first uppercase name `class Mymodel_model`

Full example on Codeigniter manual: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: Do I have to add '_model' everywhere?

Comment: Just for the record models can have any name as long as the casing is correct. There is no prerequisite to append anything to the name. In fact I have no idea where you got the idea that it needs to be that way considering the documentation you quoted has Blogmodel as the first model example. The only exception being a core library extension which needs to be MY_Model unless you do some tweaking to allow other ones.

Answer (score 0):

make the name of your model lower case all ex: "mymodel.php" and then in autoload.php just put this code $autoload['libraries'] = array('session','database');     Just get the parent construct int the model and make it simplier like this code.

```
 <?php
    class MyModel extends CI_Model
    {    
        public function functionName()
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: you have a <br/> in your <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ,, check if that one make the error ..

Answer (score 0):

Model filename should be all lowercase. @ddjikic's reply was correct and `_model` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am using codeigniter 3.0.0 and I just faced same issue in my application when I hosted it to the production site. I salved it using the capitalizing the filename (first letter) as mentioned in error.

The Capitalize and lowercase filenames are dependent on different hosting servers.

I just made the filename's first letter capital and it works fine for me. I don't know what settings my hosting server have. but it worked for me. 
You can also try, hope it can salve your error.

Example:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Enquiry_model extends CI_Model
{
}
```

As in above example my filename was **enquiry_model.php** when it gives me error.
But later I renamed it to **Enquiry_model.php** and it salved my error.